# How do I get the file path of an image in Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight

Alright, so I pulled an image off my phone, edited it, and now it's not in Desktop, Pictures, Downloads, etc. I have no idea where GIMP saved it. If I search for the file in Spotlight, it will list the file and preview it if I hover over it. How can I find the file path of said file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have multiple tips for your question :**

1. Save an another picture using Gimp and look the initial save path.
2. Do a spotlight research and drop the file result into a Terminal Window. [you will have the entire path]
3. Do a spotlight search and <kbd>Command</kbd> click your file. This will open the folder that contains your file.
4. Do a search in Finder, right-click your file and choose 'Show in Enclosing Folder'

Comment: On Yosemite you need to command double-click the search result to access the enclosing folder

Comment: I didn't have Yosemite when I asked this question, but I do now and this trick is very helpful! And I had saved another image after this one, but remembered to save it to Pictures. This one was buried in a large tree under Documents.

Comment: Sadly, #4 no longer seems to work in Yosemite - also #3 is now command + double-click

Answer (score 1):

Select the picture and then hold down the command (apple) key.
If you're not running Yosemite, the shortcut is: <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd>

The Path'll show at the bottom of the spotlight window. It's not scrollable, you might just be able to see part of it.

Or,double click on the Spotlight result to open the image, then right-click on the image windows title.

If you want a copyable text version of the path, just drag the icon next to the window title into a Terminal window.

Comment: I edited your response slightly to include the command if he's not running Yosemite.  Hope you don't mind.  :)